# How to find the median number of siblings?

Tags: statistics

Lets say we have 100 people, 50 people don't have siblings, 38 people have 1 sibling, 10 people have 2 siblings and 2 people have 3 siblings. I'm a bit confused how would I find the median number of siblings? Is this question the equivalent of having fifty-five 0s, thirty-eight 1s, ten 2s and two 3s in a sequence?

Comment: Yes. And if 55 in 100 have 0 siblings, then the median (and modal) number of siblings is 0. The lower quartile is also 0.

Comment: See results for revised question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "55 people don't have siblings, 38 people have 1 sibling, 10 people have 2 siblings and 2 people have 3 siblings." That adds to $55+38+10+2 = 105$ people, not 100. (Maybe you meant 38 to be 33.) If the truth is that more than half have no siblings, then the median is 0.

Then in R statistical software the vector `s` of numbers of siblings you report is as shown below:

```
s = c(rep(0,55), rep(1,38), rep(2,10), rep(3, 2))
summary(s)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.6095  1.0000  3.0000 
length(s);  sd(s)
## 105             # number of people reported
## 0.7402603       # sample standard deviation
```

Addendum for revised data:

```
s = c(rep(0,50), rep(1,38), rep(2,10), rep(3, 2))
summary(s)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    0.00    0.50    0.64    1.00    3.00
```

Comment: I've made a mistake, 50 don't have siblings.

Comment: The different texts and software may give different results for the median. Sorting values from smallest to largest, the 50th is 0 and 51st is 1, so the most common convention is the average the middle two and say that the median is 0.5. As you can see from my Addendum, this is the answer in R.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is equivalent, you would simply put in ascending order and find the middle number: i.e. 0- 55 times, 1- 38 times , 2- 10 times and 3- 2 times.

Hope this helps

Comment: Chronological order?

Comment: So the median in my case is 0?

Comment: Sorry I mean in ascending order

Comment: If its 50-50 then your median would simply be the average the two groups in the middle i.e. (0+1)/2=0.5. Therefore the median is 0.5.